# pandas and folium not able to convert str to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, maps, folium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hg9W.png)I'm using python folium to develop a map which displays the airports in india, im using pandas to read the data from csv and assign the coordinates to `folium.Maker` location and im getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/mapping/folium/folium/utilities.py", line 59, in validate_location
    float(coord)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#geo +lat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "map1.py", line 15, in <module>
    fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lt, ln], popup="Hi there", icon=folium.Icon(color="green")))
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/mapping/folium/folium/map.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.location = validate_location(location)
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/mapping/folium/folium/utilities.py", line 63, in validate_location
    .format(coord, type(coord)))
ValueError: Location should consist of two numerical values, but '#geo +lat' of type <class 'str'> is not convertible to float.
```

```
import folium
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("aiports.csv")
lat = list(data["latitude_deg"])
lon = list(data["longitude_deg"])


map = folium.Map(location = [20.5937 ,78.9629], zoom_start=4, tiles = "Stamen Terrain")

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")

for lt, ln in zip(lat, lon):
    fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lt, ln], popup="Hi there", icon=folium.Icon(color="green")))

map.add_child(fg)

map.save("Map1.html")
```

Comment: Please, provide the code from map1.py and an excerpt of the csv file.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: I have uploaded the code

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the contents of the dataframe and you will see first row is meta-data not data.  I just skipped first row using `loc[]`. For good measure I've include airport name in the marker.

```
df = pd.read_csv("airports.csv")
map = folium.Map(location = [20.5937 ,78.9629], zoom_start=4, tiles = "Stamen Terrain")
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")

for r in df.loc[1:,["name","latitude_deg","longitude_deg"]].to_dict(orient="records"):
    fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[r["latitude_deg"], r["longitude_deg"]], popup=r["name"], icon=folium.Icon(color="green")))

map.add_child(fg)    

map
```

**output**
[image]